# Open Cygwin/MinGW/PowerShell/Cmd in current folder open in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, terminal

Lets say I have a folder open in Windows Explorer like this:

[image]

I want that I be able to open a Cygwin terminal directly here by using keyboard shortcut or alteast by doing right click and selecting an option on the pop-up menu that makes it possible to do so. I will also often need to open MinGW, PowerShell or Windows Command Terminal in this way in specific directory.

Right now I open the terminal and then copy-paste and path and use CD command to change the directory. But, I am sure that there must be a quicker way to doing this when we need to do this dozen times everyday for decades.

I am using Windows 10 by the way, and will probably move to Windows 11 soon.